# ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have a table of data containing four columns

| 0. | 4.246579091762123e-6 | 0.03265347837226368 | 2.194410478609251 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | -0.12938661984768404 | 0.16521412970349758 | 1.856296278715755 |
| 2. | -0.6524263619026305 | 1.317312564309627 | 2.4581977984322188 |
| 3. | -1.481025225749298 | 1.5601344096178906 | 2.437032682967227 |
| 4. | -0.8045597481535853 | 1.5245713778727028 | 1.9797559186772764 |
| 5. | -0.3300249450506991 | 2.180177753839574 | 3.0821864146136346 |

I need to take the log of this table and plot the last columns against the 1st one. I have come across `ListLogLinearPlot` which, I believe works as `ListLinePlot` somehow. However, I could not get the desired result.

The above table is in a .dat file and I used the below-mentioned code:

```
data1 = Import[".../Data.dat", "Table"]
ListLinePlot[{data1[[All, {1, 2}]], data1[[All, {1, 3}]],data1[[All, {1, 4}]]}]

ListLogLinearPlot[{data1[[All, {1, 2}]], data1[[All, {1, 3}]],data1[[All, {1, 4}]]}]
```

**Could someone tell me can this process works? If yes, then how to make it work?**

Comment: ListLogLinearPlot is logarithmic on the x axis where values in your table are negative.

Comment: After reading the answer by @BobHanlon it is not clear to me if you had problems with `Export` and `Import` or manipulating the specific set of data. If the latter is the case, please let me know so I can delete my answer at it is irrelevant. Many thanks!

Comment: I didn't have a problem with importing the data file, however, you showed an alternative way without manually giving the address of the location. Thank you for that

Comment: @user84456 thanks. glad my response was a bit helpful :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{0., 4.246579091762123*^-6, 0.03265347837226368, 2.194410478609251},
   {1., -0.12938661984768404, 0.16521412970349758, 1.856296278715755},
   {2., -0.6524263619026305, 1.317312564309627, 2.4581977984322188},
   {3., -1.481025225749298, 1.5601344096178906, 2.437032682967227},
   {4., -0.8045597481535853, 1.5245713778727028, 1.9797559186772764},
   {5., -0.3300249450506991, 2.180177753839574, 3.0821864146136346}};

ListLinePlot[
 data[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4},
 PlotLegends ->
  (StringForm["Column ``", #] & /@ {2, 3, 4})]
```

[image]

On a log scale you cannot plot the first point of each curve since `Log[0]` evaluates to `-Infinity`

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
 data[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4},
 PlotLegends ->
  (StringForm["Column ``", #] & /@ {2, 3, 4}),
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can drop the first column and default the data range to `{1, 6}`

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
 data[[All, #]] & /@ {2, 3, 4},
 PlotLegends ->
  (StringForm["Column ``", #] & /@ {2, 3, 4}),
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: How about axes? They should not be the same as before as we are taking log of the data. How to correct the axes?

Comment: For a LogLinearPlot or its List equivalent, the Log is of the x variable rather than the y. Note that the spacing on the x-axis is not uniform. Because the range is limited, the difference is limited.

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure how you exported your data, so below I am showing you one way that works.

```
Quit[]

$Version
```

> `"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`

I have saved the notebook on my desktop, so when I run

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

I get

> `"/home/mylaptop'sname/Desktop"`

I am exporting in the following way. I used the same name as you did. This creates a file Data.dat on my Desktop -note I did not know what to export, so I picked some random functions.

```
Export["Data.dat", Table[{n, 2 n, 4 n, 6 n}, {n, 30}]]
```

Now we want to import in the notebook

First we

```
Quit[]
```

now we import our data

```
data1 = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "Data.dat"];
```

and we can check what we did

```
data1
```

gives

> `{{1, 2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 8, 12}, {3, 6, 12, 18}, {4, 8, 16, 24}, {5, 10,  20, 30}, {6, 12, 24, 36}, {7, 14, 28, 42}, {8, 16, 32, 48}, {9, 18,  36, 54}, {10, 20, 40, 60}, {11, 22, 44, 66}, {12, 24, 48, 72}, {13,  26, 52, 78}, {14, 28, 56, 84}, {15, 30, 60, 90}, {16, 32, 64,  96}, {17, 34, 68, 102}, {18, 36, 72, 108}, {19, 38, 76, 114}, {20,  40, 80, 120}, {21, 42, 84, 126}, {22, 44, 88, 132}, {23, 46, 92,  138}, {24, 48, 96, 144}, {25, 50, 100, 150}, {26, 52, 104,  156}, {27, 54, 108, 162}, {28, 56, 112, 168}, {29, 58, 116,  174}, {30, 60, 120, 180}}`

And now in order to do the plots you mentioned

```
ListLinePlot[{data1[[All, {1, 2}]], data1[[All, {1, 3}]], 
  data1[[All, {1, 4}]]}]

ListLogLinearPlot[{data1[[All, {1, 2}]], data1[[All, {1, 3}]], 
  data1[[All, {1, 4}]]}]
```

[image: se1]

[image: se2]

I hope it's clear

Comment: How about axes? They should not be the same as before as we are taking log of the data. How to correct the axes?

Comment: @user84456 please take a closer look at the plots. `ListLogLinearPlot` has a `Log` x-axis